# Robot framework: select element from google location API

Tags: robotframework

I am trying to select the value from google API. 
My python version is 2.7. I am scripting for google chrome.

When i start typing something in text box then the text box shows some available values. Like if I type "Del" then it shows the suggestions as Delhi, India.

Now I have scripted till entering text in text field and it is also showing the available values. But as it isn't a dropdown, I can't select the value from that list using name or index. 
I tried to press down arrow key but using ASCII value as //40 press the value as ( in the text field.

Can anyone please suggest the solution either for selection of value or pressing the down arrow key.

```
Click element    ${Location_Input}
Press Key    ${Location_Input}    P
sleep    4Seconds
Press Key    ${Location_Input}    \\40
```

Results in to : "P("

Answer (score 0):

`Press Key    ${Location_Input}    \\40` does exactly what's written in documentation, i.e. press ASCII character `(` represented by code `\\40`. Check out any ASCII table:
http://robotframework.org/Selenium2Library/Selenium2Library.html#Press%20Key

If you want to press non-ASCII key, it becomes bit more difficult.
I'd propose write e.g. extended library on top of original Selenium2Library like this:

```
# ExtendedSelenium.py
from Selenium2Library import Selenium2Library
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys


class ExtendedSelenium(Selenium2Library):

    def __init__(self):
        super(ExtendedSelenium, self).__init__()

    def press_down_arrow(self):
        """ Emulates action "press down arrow on keyboard".
        """
        ActionChains(self._current_browser()).send_keys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN, Keys.NULL).perform()
```

...and then call it from you RF code:

```
Library    ExtendedSelenium.py

*** Test Cases ***
Your Test
    ...
    Press Down Arrow
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks Jan for quick response, I am pretty much sure that this will work, But as a beginner I am not getting exactly where and how to do it. 
what I did is copied your code in one text file, saved it as ExtendedSelenium.py under folder C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\Selenium2Library. and mentioned it in my RF code and callled the down arrow. But looks like I am making some mistake. 
Can you please guide me.

Comment: I kept the lib file at location "C:\Python27\Lib", It shows the error as 
launch browser :: launching browser                                   | FAIL |
Multiple keywords with name 'Open Browser' found. Give the full name of the keyword you want to use:
    ExtendedSelenium.Open Browser
    Selenium2Library.Open Browser

Comment: Ah, I forgot to mention that in case of such library inheritance it is supposed (and needed) that the new extended library will be used instead of the original Selenium2Library, not together.

Comment: Thanks a lot....Its working now.  I was struggling with this from last two days...Now got the solution. Thanks a lot again.

Comment: Hi Jan, Can you please let me know the same for pressing tab key? I have an situation where I just want to press a tab key without giving attribute, can you please suggest me how I can modify the above class or do I need to crate a seperate class and what code need to added in that class? thanks in advance. Opening the question for you.

Comment: No new class needed. Just a new method (keyword) inside existing class. Use `TAB` instead of `ARROW_DOWN`.

Comment: Updated the library as below::::  
 def press_tab(self):
  """Emulates action "press tab on keyboard".
  """
  ActionChains(self._current_browser()).send_keys(Keys.TAB, Keys.NULL).perform() :::::

called from code as ::::
Press TAB  ::::

Getting error as No keyword with press tab found

Kindly suggest where I am doing wrong?

Comment: Did you imported your custom library in your robot code `*** Settings ***`?

Comment: Yes
*** Settings ***
Documentation     Sample test case
Library           robot.libraries.DateTime
Library           String
Library           ExtendedSelenium.py

Comment: It is working perfect for down arrow, so I dont think there could be any problem wiith accessing the library. there might be any problem with pressing TAB,

Comment: Then I have no idea without broader view into the code. Could you please enhance your question and share particular part of you python and robot code?

Comment: As you suggested, I have updated the extended library as below.
    def press_down_arrow(self):
        """ Emulates action "press down arrow on keyboard".
        """
        ActionChains(self._current_browser()).send_keys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN, Keys.NULL).perform()

 def press_tab(self):
  """Emulates action "press tab on keyboard".
  """
  ActionChains(self._current_browser()).send_keys(Keys.TAB, Keys.NULL).perform()


I am using the the code as press tab key in my code as below:

Press TAB

but its not working.No keyword with name 'Press TAB' found.

Comment: Its quite critical stage for me. Kindly help me out. or give me your email ID so that I can share the exact code with some screen shots.